# Run python subprocess using Popen independently

Tags: python, linux

I wanted to run execute a python script as a UNIX shell command independently using python `Popen`.

`Script1.py` : This script will take multiple arguments.
`Script2.py` : This script will parse some conditions and will prepare necessary arguments needed to call `Script1.py`

Assume `Script2.py` parsed some conditions and prepared a command to run Script1.py
**Command** : `python Script1.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

Currently running the script as :

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(Command,shell=True,stdout=None, stderr=None)
```

But, when I kill `Script2.py` manually(using CTRL+C), I could see that Script1.py is also getting killed/Terminated.

How can I run `Script1.py` independently without worrying about status of `Script2.py`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to detach a process from its parent on `window$` is:

```
from subprocess import Popen

CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
Popen(['python', 'drive:/path/to/loop_test.py', 'some_arg', 'another_arg'],
                 stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=True,
                 creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
                 )
```

On `linux` you should be able to achieve the same using `nohup` and `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp`, i.e.:

```
Popen(['nohup', 'python', '/path/to/loop_test.py', 'some_arg','another_arg'],
shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp )
```

Comment: Thanks....It worked!. 
Can you please let me know what will "preexec_fn=os.setpgrp" do?

Comment: @BharathK  [`os.setpgrp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.setpgrp) - _Call the system call `setpgrp()` or `setpgrp(0, 0)` depending on which version is implemented (if any). See the Unix manual for the semantics._

Comment: Note: You can directly use `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` and `subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS` instead of specifying those values yourself. Also note that just `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` should be enough if all you want is to prevent the CTRL + C from stopping parent.